# How to post multiple Select values using HttpWebRequest in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, httpwebrequest

my goal is to use Asp.Net's HttpWebRequest to submit multiple values to a webpage, as if they were sent from a `<select>` element.

The code i use for creating the data string is as follows:

```
NameValueCollection outgoingQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);
outgoingQueryString.Add("username", "myusername");
outgoingQueryString.Add("password", "mypassword");
string postData = outgoingQueryString.ToString();
```

Now lets say I have the following select for example:

```
<select name="banana" multiple="">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

I need to submit options 1 and 2, how do i add this to the query string? as an array, or can i add several values with the same name?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: since you have only one querystring key i.e. `banana` found in `<select>` , how can you expect to pass multiple values for same key?

Comment: how can that value be "1" and "2" at the same time?

Comment: When you select multiple options in a select element, how are they being posted? Is it possible to emulate that using the httpwebrequest?

Comment: Workaround can be, just pass comma separated value and on receiving end, parse those comma to get list of values.

Comment: @arindamnayak, the receiving end is not being handled by me, is there a way to emulate standard select element?

Comment: You can pass comma separated values, i am going to post my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass comma separed values, because when you do actually post a multi select control, you get comma separated values in `Request`, so to emulate, you can pass comma separated values.

[image]

Following HTML used. Note `select` is a server control here.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <select name="banana" multiple="" id="sl" runat="server">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="sub" OnClick="btn_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply Use `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList MyArray;

if (Request.QueryString["MyArray"] != null)
{
   MyArray = (ArrayList)Request.QueryString["MyArray"];
}

else
{
  MyArray = new ArrayList();
}
```

Add values to `ArrayList`

```
 if (MyArray.IndexOf(checkAllIndex) == -1)
   {

    MyArray.Add(checkAllIndex);
   }
```

Remove from `ArrayList`

```
if (MyArray.IndexOf(checkAllIndex) != -1)

        {

            MyArray.Remove(checkAllIndex);
         }
```

Comment: it says it cannot cast String to ArrayList

Comment: `MyArray = (ArrayList)Request.QueryString["MyArray"];` - `cannot convert type 'string' to System.Collections.ArrayList`

Comment: i think you are adding like this `MyArray.Add("1,2,3");`

Comment: thing is, that i dont add at all. i dont know how it passed the null check in the first place.

Comment: please edit:question and paste your code so can find out easily

Comment: its alright, my issue has been resolved. thanks for the help anyway